# Find expressions for the mean and variance of X.

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, variance

We say that $X$ is a discrete uniform random variable if $X$ takes any of the values
$1, 2, . . . , n$ equally likely. That is, $P[X = i] = 1/n$ for $i = 1, . . . , n$.

Find expressions for
the mean and variance of X.

My attempt:

$E[X] = \sum{xp(x)} =\sum_{i=1}^n{ i×1/n} = \sum_{i=1}^n{i/n}$

$Var[X] = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(i-\sum_{i=1}^n{i/n})^2}{n}$

Is my attempt correct, how do I continue expressing $Var[X]$?

Comment: No it is not correct. What is $i$? The expectation should only depend on $n$ (as should the variance). How did you evaluate the sum?

Comment: Can you check my edit?

Comment: Can you find an expression for $\sum_{i=1}^ni$ in $n$? What is $1+2+\cdots+n$?

Comment: @drhab yes, it is $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

Comment: Yes, it is better now. But you can evaluate these sums, see tommik's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n i=\frac{n+1}{2}$$

$$\mathbb{V}[X]=\mathbb{E}[X^2]-\mathbb{E}^2[X]$$

that is

$$\mathbb{V}[X]=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n i^2-\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^2=$$

$$=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6n}-\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^2=...$$